# Can papaParse be modified to work in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, papaparse

At my job most if not all employees use IE8. I know the faq page in papaParse says IE10+ preferred. My questions is has anyone modified it to work with older versions of IE?

The error thrown by IE is:

Object doesn't support this property or method

The line of code which it refers to is:

NetworkStreamer.prototype = Object.create(ChunkStreamer.prototype);

Comment: Never done it, but you could try [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim). However, I strongly recommend you and your coworkers upgrade their browser or switch to Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: It's beyond my control to the choice of browser. And I'm also limited to browser only solutions :/